# JavaScript Regex finding all substrings matching the starting and ending pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I want a Javascript regex which, in a given string finds all the substrings that start with a particular character and end with a particular character.
The returned set of subStrings can be an Array.
eg
STRING:

```
Body<input value="CourseName" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseDescription" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseEnrollmentDeadline" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">"
```

starting char = `"<input"`
ending char = `">"`

output:

```
<input value="CourseName" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
<input value="CourseDescription" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
<input value="CourseEnrollmentDeadline" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
```

Comment: you don't want a regex you want document.querySelector(), if you desperately need regex try something lik new RegExp("/"+"start_pattern"+"([^"+end_pattern+end_pattern+"]+)/g"), but you don't want to do that either, because you wouldn't know if someinput is \\s then it becomes a regex special charecter. so its a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a regex like so:

```
var string = 'Body<input value="CourseName" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseDescription" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseEnrollmentDeadline" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">';

var re = /\<input.*?\>/ig
var match;
while ((match = re.exec(string)) != null){
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Produces:

```
<input value="CourseName" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
<input value="CourseDescription" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
<input value="CourseEnrollmentDeadline" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">
```

However, as has been pointed out in the comments, this is probably not the best idea.

**Edit** (as per your request in the comments):

```
var string = 'Body<input value="CourseName" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseDescription" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button"><input value="CourseEnrollmentDeadline" class="emailButtonSnip" type="button">';

var re = /\<input.*?\>/ig
var match;
while ((match = re.exec(string)) != null){
  var input = match[0],
      re1 = /value="(.*?)"/ig;
  console.log(re1.exec(input)[1]);
}
```

Produces:

```
CourseName
CourseDescription
CourseEnrollmentDeadline
```

You could of course just match the values in your original string straight off, but as I have no idea what you're trying t do, I'll leave it like this.

Comment: can you please help to get the value from each of the sub string.
eg for first output is CourseName,
  for second output is CourseDescription, and for third output is CourseEnrollmentDeadline

Comment: Why are you using a regex to do this? It is very messy. Why not `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: Actually i am not accessing this content from html
i already have this string as a value of an element.
My use case is to parse this string and replace the input div's, just with their values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack.
Really obliged with your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<[^>]+>
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/11

Comment: This awesome . But would have loved more if there is a little bit of explanation.

Comment: @JPS there is an explanation in the link above.let me know if you need more info